# Objective-C direct upload on YouTube

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-upload, youtube-api, video-encoding

I am having a problem uploading video with my app. I see the video in My Videos on YouTube, but then it says: "unable to convert video file". I uploaded this video through the native YouTube uploader successfully. Please tell me that wrong with my code, and what the error means.

Code here:

```
-(NSString*) GetHeader{
       NSString* xml = [[NSString alloc] init];
       xml = [xml stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@
%@Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8%@%@",kboundary,
klineTerm, klineTerm, klineTerm]];

       xml = [xml stringByAppendingString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"];
       xml = [xml stringByAppendingString:@"<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/
2005/Atom\" xmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\" xmlns:yt=
\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\"> <media:group><media:title
type=\"plain\">Movie.m4v</media:title><media:description type=\"plain
\">I gave a bad toast at my friends wedding.</
media:description><media:category scheme=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/
schemas/2007/categories.cat\">People</
media:category><media:keywords>toast, wedding</media:keywords></
media:group></entry>\r\n"];

       xml=[xml stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@
%@Content-Type: video/m4v%@Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary%@
%@",kboundary,klineTerm,klineTerm,klineTerm,klineTerm]];
       return xml;
}

-(IBAction)uploadVideoByAuthKey:(id)respons{
       NSMutableData* requestBody;
       const char *utfMyString = [[self GetHeader] UTF8String];
       const char *utfMyString1=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@
%@--",klineTerm,kboundary] UTF8String];
       requestBody=[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:utfMyString
length:strlen(utfMyString)+1];

       //Add video file in body
       NSURL* URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Movie"
withExtension:@"m4v"];

       NSData*file=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
       [requestBody appendData:file];
       [requestBody appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:utfMyString1
length:strlen(utfMyString1)+1]];

       //Create request
       NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kVideoRequestURL]];
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
       [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/related;
boundary=%@;",kboundaryheader] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
       [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[requestBody
length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
       [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin auth=
%@",authKey] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
       [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@",kdevKey]
forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-GData-Key"];
       [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Movie.m4v"]
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Slug"];
       [request addValue:@"add_video_to_youtube" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-
GData-Client" ];
       [request setHTTPBody: requestBody];
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you use the [official SDK](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/)? Did you try intercepting the HTTP request to make sure it’s not malformed?

Comment: I did't use official SDK because I need only upload video file. Of course I will use the official SDK  if I will not find solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `Content-Type: video/m4v` to `Content-Type: video/x-m4v`